# What is the Catholic Church's position on a divorced man attending services

Tags: catholicism, denomination-survey, religious-practice, religious-education

I would like to join a Catholic church with my 13 year old son. I am a 47 year old man that was divorced in 2006. If I’m able to, I would like to find a Catholic church for my son and to attend services, take communion, and be able to confess. I would also like to attend a Sunday type school or bible study with my son to get him up to speed on his faith. Am I able to accomplish this as a divorced man in this day and age?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the site and asking a question here.  We try to provide objective answers to questions about Christian doctrine and refer all requests for pastoral advice to personal spiritual advisors.  I think we can address this question, and we probably have in the past.  I'll see if I can dig up a related question...

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33525/who-may-receive-holy-communion-in-a-catholic-church https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42350/according-to-traditional-catholicism-what-is-the-spiritual-solution-for-the-div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who may receive Holy Communion in a Catholic Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33525/who-may-receive-holy-communion-in-a-catholic-church)

Answer (score 2):

By "[divorce](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33173)" I assume you mean separation from your wife. This is not necessarily a sin; what lead to it might be, which is why you should consult a priest and confess your sins to him. To "remarry" another woman while your wife is still alive is the serious sin of adultery.

Any Catholic can and should confess his sins to a priest in the sacrament of confession. All that's required for a Catholic to worthily receive Holy Communion is to be in the state of grace (no [mortal sin](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34987) on your soul) and to have fasted at least an hour before.